# Display Alert box through the trigger - salesforce

Tags: salesforce, apex-code, force.com

Is it possible to display an alert message (not error message) through a trigger? I have written a trigger that checks for duplicate accounts in the system. The trigger at the moment gives an error message to the user telling that there is a duplicate account. But, if the user changes the value of a field "Is record near to duplicate?" to YES, the trigger allows the user to save the record.

But, I want to display the error message in an alert pop up box like "Account with this Name exists,are you sure you want to continue" and then user clicks Yes and the record gets created. Any thoughts on how I can do this. My code is below:

```
for(Account account: System.Trigger.New)  
{  
 if(accountMap.containsKey(account.Physical_Street__c)==accountMap2.containsKey(account.Phone))
 if(accountMap.containsKey(account.Physical_Street__c)==accountMap3.containsKey(account.Name))  
 if(account.Is_record_near_to_duplicate__c.equals('No'))  
  {  
   account.addError('Account with this Name,Street and Phone Number already      exists. If you still wish to create the agency change the value of field "Is Record Near To Duplicate" to YES');  
  }  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you really need an alert box then you could create a custom javascript button that uses the [ajax toolkit](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/ajax/index.htm) to replace the standard save button.

However, as Baxter said you are getting pretty far from standard salesforce look and feel. I would recommend instead to add an error on the checkbox field instead of the object so it is clear to the user what they need to select.

```
if(account.Is_record_near_to_duplicate__c.equals('No'))  
  {  
     account.Is_record_near_to_duplicate__c.addError('Agency with this Name, Physical Street and Phone Number already exists. If you still wish to create the agency change the value of field "Is Record Near To Duplicate" to YES');  
  }
```

Comment: Thanks, can you pls suggest how can the error message be displayed using the VF page. I am not sure how I can achieve that.

Comment: Do you mean if you build a custom vf page? In that case you would of course be in full control of the page and could display the error however you want. You would need to create a javascript function to display the alert box and call that function from the commandbutton that saves the record. I.E.
`
code
<apex:commandButton action="{!save}" value="Save" id="theButton" oncomplete="displayalert({!errormessage})"/>
`
Note that since you are replacing the standard salesforce error behaviour you would want to catch any errors in your save function and put them in the errormessage string.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you write a custom visualforce page that processes the error message and then displays it as a popup there's no way to do this.

If you wanted the alert to modify the data you may look at using the ajax api to set the Is_record_near_to_duplicate__c field to 'Yes' but either way you're getting pretty far from the standard functionality and interface with this.

Answer (score 0):

It is not straight forward to implement a pop-up alert for a trigger error, and pop-ups went out-of-fashion a long time ago. If you are going through the hassle, you might as well implement a custom soultion on a VF page.

Throw a custom exception(for dupe accounts) from the trigger, and catch it in your controller. When you catch this exception, you can dynamically displayed  section on the page which asks the user to confirm his/her action. When the user confirms the action, the page will do the rest.

Hope this makes sense!

Anup